# REST logout without logout_token

Tags: 8

I have a small app I'm working on and after I created a new build I'm unable to login or logout. This seems to happen because drupal thinks I'm logged in but my app doesn't have the user details in local storage. So I don't know the `logout_token` needed to logout from app.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Why can't you login again to get a new session/tokens? Does your Drupal configuration prevent multiple sessions with the same UID?

Comment: Been a while but I'm assuming that they were running into the same problem I do when using REST with cookies.  Attempts to re-login aren't possible when a session cookie already exists; Drupal rejects attempts to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Marius,

When you login using rest api, csrf and logout tokens are generated. use the logout_token generated to logout form your app. Make a post request to

```
/user/logout?_format=json&token={logout_token}
```

Sample code to logout from your app will be similar to

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.withCredentials = true;

 xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
   if (this.readyState === 4) {
     console.log(this.responseText);
   }
 });

 xhr.open("POST", "http://example.com/user/logout?_format=json&token=logout_token");
 xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");

 xhr.send(data);
```

Hope that helps.

[image: Logout][image: Login]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookie based login you can go into the Application tab then on the left hand side Cookies > your-site-name in the dev console and delete the cookie that starts with SESS. This will log you out. To the best of my knowledge there isn't a way to request a logout_token after it is initially created during /user/login. So in your case if you still have an active session (using cookies) you are sort of stuck. I just submitted a patch for review in core which addresses this. I'd kindly ask that review it and make suggestions if you have a chance. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3004421